# Eclipse or intelliJ IDEA for selenium webdriver (java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am concerned about which **IDE** to use for writing my *selenium webdriver* **java** test scripts so that it will be easy for me to create and maintain my tests.

I would also like to know the **pros** and **cons** and difference between **Eclipse** and **intelliJ IDEA**.

Please **brief** me!

Thanks Already!!

Comment: Short answer: either one will do the job just fine. This is bound to get downvotes though since it's asking for opinions :(

Comment: I just want a clear answer : Eclipse OR intelliJ IDEA and why? :)

Comment: I was a newb in selenium and used Eclipse, but that was just because I had used it before. IDE's are not that important, I believe. Just use what you're accustomed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with intelliJ IDEA is a good practice if you are new to the world of selenium webdriver as it less complex to statrup and its smart Code completion is very helpful.

Comment: There is even special plugin for Selenium tests in IntelliJ IDEA: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13267-qa-lithium