# convert python selenium to just selenium ide commands

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below I have a python script that is able to perform the following:

- Find the current date selected
- Select the next available date
- If no    available date is found within the month, press next to go to next    month

My question is that I also just want to included a selenium ide verson only where the person just needs to record their steps. Is there a way to convert the code I have below into commands, targets and values in IDE so it does the same thing? If you can provide a list of the commands, targets and values in order then will be really helpful.

The website I'm testing on is www.jet2.com and it's in regards to the departure date.

Reason I just want to convert in IDE only is so in future when manual testing, I can just use the IDE playback to perform the rest of the tests. The claendar was the only glitch I had which is solved using the python method.

```
# select date
datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-date-selector")
actions.move_to_element(datepicker).click().perform()

# find the calendar, month and year picker and the current date
calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("departureDateContainer")
month_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month"))
year_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
current_date = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-current-day")

# printing out current date
month = month_picker.first_selected_option.text
year = year_picker.first_selected_option.text
print("Current date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=current_date.text, month=month, year=year))

# see if we have an available date in this month
try:
    next_available_date = current_date.find_element_by_xpath("following::td[@data-handler='selectDay' and ancestor::div/@id='departureDateContainer']")
    print("Found an available date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
# looping over until the next available date found
        while True:
# click next, if not found, select the next year
            try:
                calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next").click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
# select next year
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
                year.select_by_visible_text(str(int(year.first_selected_option.text) + 1))

# reporting current processed month and year
                month = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month")).first_selected_option.text
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year")).first_selected_option.text
                print("Processing {month} {year}".format(month=month, year=year))

            try:
                next_available_date = calendar.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-handler='selectDay']")
                print("Found an available date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
                next_available_date.click()
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                continue
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but before you consider IDE in your long-term plans it might be worth checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683100/why-do-we-use-webdriver-instead-of-selenium-ide

Comment: Hi andrew, I actually viewed this page before. I want to use IDE so then I can show those who are new to automation a quick way to get into it before using web driver when we go more advanced down the road. Some testers don't have a development background you see

Comment: OK, but I think the attitude from Selenium is that WebDriver is the standard rather than the advanced approach, and non-devs should use one of the many frameworks or DSLs. Having managed non-technical testers I'd say that they can be at least as productive with a decent DSL as with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I's impossible with pure Selenium IDE but you can use plugins like
[FlowControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/) or [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/) to get if-else, goto and loop functionality
as well as javascript-like conditionals, callable functions, error catching, and JSON/XML driven parametrization.