# Can I run Selenium Test Cases using a library in an extension?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have a file with the exported test case.
Can I build a browser extension (e.g, in Chrome) that uses some Selenium Core library which would simply run the test? I mean I'd just write something like

```
var selenium = require(<this is the library I'm looking for>)
var testCase ="<the html code of a test case exported form Selenium IDE>";
selenium.run(testCase);
```

I failed to find any simple JS library that would make it possible.
Is it possible?

Comment: The whole point of test automation is to get ride of manual intervention. So why would you ask someone to manually load and run a suite in a browser?

Comment: @FlorentB. I want to have the test cases saved in my own (chrome) extension and run them as a complementary functionality of the extension, without manual intervention. So, do you think, is there a way?

Comment: Selenium doesn't have a JS library to automate Chrome. The chrome driver is implemented in c++: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/

Comment: @FlorentB. thank you! Still I fail to understand one thing. Selenium IDE has to be able to run the tests and selenium IDE must be written in Javascript, because it is a browser extension. How can this be possible?

Comment: The extension `Selenium IDE` has its own library to drive Firefox and doesn't share anything with `Selenium WebDriver`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683100/why-do-we-use-webdriver-instead-of-selenium-ide

Comment: @FlorentB. ok, so let's talk about Selenium IDE. 1. Is there any way to run the tests written in selenium ide outside the selenium IDE (in firefox)? I'm looking for a domain-specific language similar to selenium IDE language (which is actually just a sequence of commands) that could run in javascript, preferably in a browser extension.

Comment: You should drop `Selenium IDE`, the recorder is not reliable. Have a look at Nightwatch (http://nightwatchjs.org/), it has a similar syntax.